# Chrome extension "fails" to register service worker in citrix

Tags: google-chrome-extension, citrix, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

While developing a chrome extension and delivering to users via GPO, for some reason after the installation of the extension on chrome the service worker do not register on chrome in Citrix environment. That seems to be a problem only with Manifest V3.
Things to note:

1. Installation is successful on chrome, I can see the icon on `chrome://extensions/`, but the service worker appears "Inactive".
2. This particular extension is hosted on private web server.
3. After restarting chrome, sometimes the service worker is successfully registered.
4. To see if the service worker was registered, I checked on `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`.

What I have tried so far:

1. When the installation is successful, on the service worker I used this approach:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (value) {
    if (value.reason == 'install') {
        setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.runtime.reload();
            console.log('Reload!');
        }, 2000)
    }
})
```

But since the service worker keeps "Inactive" and not registered on `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, it didn't work.

2. I checked that the problem only happens in Citrix environment with non-permanent images, meaning that the extension will install in every user logon via GPO.
3. This extension does not have a default popup, it's supposed to work entirely on service workers, without a user interface.
4. I checked that with manifest V2 extensions, on the same environment, everything works fine.
5. If I add a popup, sometimes when the user clicks on the popup, the registration of the worker starts. Same behavior as restarting chrome.
6. I did not find any mention to this problem anywhere, since it's so specific.

Note: I can't share any part of the service worker since it's a private extension, but I'll share the manifest below, but keep in mind that the installation works fine as I mentioned before.

So, I'm looking for any idea on what is going on before sending an issue on chrome.

## manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "css": [ "logic.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [ "storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "webNavigation", "nativeMessaging" ],
  "host_permissions": [ "https://*/*" ],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/logo16.png",
      "32": "/images/logo32.png",
      "48": "/images/logo48.png",
      "128": "/images/logo128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/logo16.png",
    "32": "/images/logo32.png",
    "48": "/images/logo48.png",
    "128": "/images/logo128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you have a content script there's a workaround: call chrome.runtime.sendMessage and if it fails, add an iframe to the web page pointing to an html file exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/). Inside this iframe you'll have a standard extension environment where you can use `navigator.serviceWorker` to re-register your background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Didn't try yet but makes sense. Since I can't edit the question right now, just openened a new issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1417640#makechanges