# Chrome extension v3 Service Worker; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am writing a chrome extension v3. In my background.js, I keep getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')

Here is the code

```
// background.js
// Check if the service worker API is supported
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  // Register the service worker
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("background.js")
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service worker registered:", registration);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error registering service worker:", error);
    });
}

// Handle the message event
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  var request = event.data;
  if (request.type === "search") {
    // Perform the searches and send the results back to the content script
    var title = request.title;
    var title2 = title.replace(/ /g, "+"); // Replace spaces with +
    var results = [];
    var queries = [
      `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=${title}`,
      `https://www.biorxiv.org/search/${title}`,
      `https://www.medrxiv.org/search/${title}`,
      `https://www.google.com/search?q=${title2}+filetype:pdf`
    ];
    queries.forEach(function (query) {
      fetch(query)
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (html) {
          // Extract the relevant information from the HTML using cheerio or regular expressions
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);
          // ...
          results.push( /* Extract the relevant information */);
        });
    });

    // Send the results back to the content script
    event.ports[0].postMessage({ results: results });
  }
});
```

The error persists even when I delete the check section, i.e., the section that says `// Check if the service worker API is supported`
Any clues?

Comment: There's no need to register SW in ManifestV3, remove all that code. See also [how to send messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, trying that again (delete the check/register section) worked now... somehow it's not working earlier

But now the icon still can't be clicked on click once it's loaded, any suggestions?

Comment: @wOxxOm that might be needed, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74643300/chrome-extension-fails-to-register-service-worker-in-citrix

Comment: @ojonasplima, maybe but definitely not inside the SW.

Comment: @Kuan, what icon? Show your new code.

Comment: @wOxxOm the icon for the extension, but when i checked it looks like it could be this bug? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271154#c52

Comment: `background.js` is the same as above but no check/register section. `manifest.json` is 
```{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Get Free Copy",
  "description": "Searches for free copies of research papers on various websites",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest","tabs","webRequest", "webNavigation"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: You need to declare `"action": {}` to be able to use chrome.action API.

Comment: That worked, still a ways to go to completing my first extension, thanks a ton All